# Using Observer stop execution of next function in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer, error, sales-order, admin-panel

I am using an observer on **event** `sales_order_save_before` to check for a condition and based on that condition I was to stop the save functionality.

Currently I am using it on `Submit Comment` in Sales Order view (Admin Panel)

My Observer `execute` function is called and condition is met. but it doesn't stop the save functionality when I raise error using `throw new \ErrorException()`

Is there any other way to completely stop the save order process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I learnt from magento 2 certification exam : `the data that is sent to events should not be transformed. Events should be able to be run completely asynchronously`, so around plugin can be used to stop logic.
For `Submit Comment` create aroundExecute() for Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddComment

```
public function aroundExecute(AddComment $subject, \Closure $proceed){
    //your statement;
    if (your statement) {
       proceed();
    }
    else{
       // stop original chain
       //adderrorMassage();
       redirect or throw Error;
       return;
    }

}
```